# Storing values in matrices with different dimensions in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

My RHSvec is a 51X21 matrix. kdpolind is 11X51X21. Doing the following:

```
[RHSval,kprimeind] = max(RHSvec,[],2);
```

gives me a 51X1 RHSval and a 51X1 kprimeind.
if kprimeind is as follows:

```
16
20
20
16
20
16
16
```

then I want to store in kprimeind in kdpolind as

```
kdpolind(act,1,16)
kdpolind(act,2,20)
kdpolind(act,3,20)
kdpolind(act,4,16)
```

...
I am unable to do this due to dimensions mismatch. Is there a simple way of doing this?
Thanks!

Comment: What is `act`? It should be in range 1:11.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want something like this:

An example of how to insert a matrix of a different size into another matrix

```
sub = randn(2,3); % Will give a random matrix of 2 rows and 3 columns
M   = nan(3,4,5); % Creates a nan matrix of 3 by 4 by  5
M(2,2+(1:size(sub,1)),2+(1:size(sub,2))) = sub    % Inserts the sub matrix into M with an offset of 2 (can be set to 0 for no offset)
```

will give:

```
M(:,:,1) =

   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN


M(:,:,2) =

   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN


M(:,:,3) =

       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
       NaN       NaN    0.3252   -0.7549
       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN


M(:,:,4) =

       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
       NaN       NaN    1.3703   -1.7115
       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN


M(:,:,5) =

       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
       NaN       NaN   -0.1022   -0.2414
       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
```